# Where can I find USGS SRTM 3 index grid or what procedure should I employ to select tiles?

Tags: dem, srtm

I would like to download all USGS SRTM 3 tiles for Ontario, Canada from the USGS site: http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/North_America/

Where can I obtain the index that will assist me in querying the tiles I need to download. Alternatively, is there another easier way to identify the tiles?

When I was downloading the tiles for Manitoba, Canada I found a range of files then just downloaded the individual files from the site. Is there a similar range of files for Ontario?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/Documentation/Continent_def.gif

You can use http://www.latlontoelevation.com/ lat/lng to get the Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) data too.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that I should should have read the file names before asking the question...